# getting error on hive start

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am getting below error using query

select count(*) from table;

```
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/yarn/exceptions/YarnException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider.create(YarnClientProtocolProvider.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1020)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 25 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Please help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to get the real error, go to the hadoop jobtracker web-dashboard, find the hive mapreduce jobs that failed and look at the logs of the failed tasks. The console output errors are useless, largely because they don't have a view of the individual jobs/tasks to pull the real errors (there could be errors in multiple tasks).

Comment: thanks for reply chridam..I am using yarn and getting below services started after jps command.                                                             18145 NodeManager
17010 DataNode
16885 NameNode
27948 Jps
17198 SecondaryNameNode
18463 ResourceManager